# jQuery get data into an array

Tags: jquery

I got few elements with `data-replyid`, and it is with class `post`.

By using `$('.post')` I will get an array of the elements.

By using `$('.post').data('replyid')` I will get only the data from the first elements.

How can I get all the `data-replyid` into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop and get each element with class `post` by:

```js
var arr = [];

$( ".post" ).each(function(){
 var replyid = $( this ).data('replyid');
        arr.push( replyid  );
});

console.log( arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post" data-replyid="1"> </div>
<div class="post" data-replyid="2"> </div>
<div class="post" data-replyid="3"> </div>
<div class="post" data-replyid="4"> </div>
```

Comment: @SoYuJe I updated my answer. It is storing now on array `arr`

Comment: I thought there will be a shorter way to initialize into an array.